# Radial Gradient, for plot bands on a gauge?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Alrighty so I've run into an interesting little problem. I am trying to create a gauge chart, which then has plot bands. Simple enough.

The complication comes in when I want the plot bands to have a gradient run through the center of if evenly.

A rough js fiddle I forked:

http://jsfiddle.net/maraket/omez0n9r/3/

It should be noticed I am trying a radialgradient with a sharp change as per:

```
{
        color: {
          radialGradient: {
            cx: 0.5,
            cy: 0.5,
            r: 0.5
          },
          stops: [
            [0, '#000000'],
            [0.8, '#ffffff'],
            [1, '#000000'],
          ]
        },
        from: 0,
        to: 100,
        innerRadius: '90%',
        outerRadius: '110%'
      }
```

Now for a single plotband I noticed that the radial Gradient is more eliptical then circular which makes the solution I'm using not ideal. Furthermore when using multiple plotbands this solution won't work, since it uses the local plotbands x,y which changes if there are multiple plot bands. Any thoughts would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why gradient is elliptical is because the bounding box of the plot band is not a square, but more a rectangle. It is because, you don't use full angle. Compare the gradient with full angle pane - http://jsfiddle.net/3mm1bjqf/.

Because your bounding box is not a square, then you need to define your own coordinate system for the gradient. Gradient attributes can be obtained from axis properties.

Your gradient should look like this:

```
 plotBands: [{
   color: {
    radialGradient: {
      gradientUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse', // we use our own coord system instead of bbox
      cx: axis.left + axis.center[0],
      cy: axis.top + axis.center[1],
      r: axis.center[2] / 2 * 1.1 // multiplying by 1.1 because plotBand's outerRadius is set to 110%
    },
```

Unfortunately, this gradient must be set dynamically because you do not know axis coords before the chart is rendered - so it must be done on load/redraw events.

```
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
  renderTo: 'container',
  type: 'gauge',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var axis = this.yAxis[0];

      axis.update({
        plotBands: [{
          color: {
            radialGradient: {
              gradientUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse',
              cx: axis.left + axis.center[0],
              cy: axis.top + axis.center[1],
              r: axis.center[2] / 2 * 1.1
            },
            stops: [
              [0, '#000000'],
              [0.8, '#ffffff'],
              [1, '#000000'],
            ]
          },
          from: 0,
          to: 100,
          innerRadius: '90%',
          outerRadius: '110%'
        }]
      })
    }
  }
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/zfyzvqw1/